# Convert seconds to years days hours minutes format in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to convert the seconds to years days hours minutes format in GSheet. I am using seconds/86400 and then using a custom format yy" years "dd" days "hh"  hours "mm" minutes". But result always has 1 day difference from expected output. How can I solve it ?

[Sample Google Sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1K_CnEPhvFbEuCQsmA7UgwUlCGLw5mIV54R8MoNH94cs/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: This is not an excel question, as using the number format in excel produces the result you expected. Suggest researching the nuances of Google Sheets date handling.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an arrayformula to do it (cell B1, deleting everything below):

```
=index({"Convert to  "" X years X days X hours X minutes"" format";if(A2:A<>"",int(A2:A/60/60/24/365.25)&" years "&int(mod(A2:A/60/60/24,365.25))&" days "&int(mod(A2:A/60/60,24))&" hours "&int(mod(A2:A/60,60))&" minutes",)})
```

[image]

Comment: it doesnt count for leap days

Answer (score 0):

this will never work because there is no zero day/month in history of humankind

1. January of year 0000 minus one day is 31. December of year -0001

to convert unix / epoch time use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A,
 TEXT(DATEDIF(DATE(1970, 1, 1), TEXT(A2:A/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), "Y"), "00")&" years "&
 TEXT(DATEDIF(DATE(1970, 1, 1), TEXT(A2:A/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "yyyy-mm-dd"), "YD"), "00")&" days "&
 TEXT(A2:A/86400+DATE(1970, 1, 1), "hh \hour\s mm \minut\e\s"), ))
```

[image]